# Pydev praw.Reddit error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, reddit, praw

I'm trying to create my first Reddit bot using the praw package. I'm coding in Pydev for Eclipse.

I'm getting an error that I can't figure out how to resolve. When defining an instance of Reddit, I'm using this line of code:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
```

That's the format I have seen in a bunch of code examples from a bunch of different sites.

Pydev is giving me the following error message:

> Undefined variable from import: Reddit

I can't find any source that shows how to resolve this issue. I'd appreciate some help.

EDIT:
Though the error message remains, I can still run the bot without issues. I don't understand why that would be, and would still like to know if I should try to fix something, but am glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `praw` to the forced builtins? (to force it to be dynamically analyzed through a shell)

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins for more details on the matter.

Comment: I did do that. For whatever reason it shows an error before compiling and running, but when I run it runs successfully. It even works pretty much perfectly.